# Mobile number pattern not working

Tags: html, validation

I have an input form

```
<form name=... >
...
<input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" pattern="(7|8|9)\d{9}" 
title="Please enter valid 10-digit mobile number" class="form-control" 
placeholder="10 digit mobile number" required />
...
</form>
```

When I enter a valid input: 9123010101, it pops up the default error message about "please match the format requested".

I have checked the regex in regex tester online and it matches perfectly. I am using latest Chrome browser. Please help me understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: it seems perfect, and it is working too. make sure you're not typing extra chracter such as space

Comment: Can you produce a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cud95sq8/2/) or something showing it not working?  Are there any other controls that might be failing?  Are you sure you're entering the value you say and no other spaces or tabs?

Comment: Must have been an issue with the browser. Restarted the browser and it started working fine. Thanks for your inputs guys!

Answer (score 0):

How about this? `/(7|8|9)\d{9}/`

Add reverse slashes in the begin and the end of pattern and make sure you're not typing extra chracter such as space

Comment: Hey I tried that too. But didn't work. Seems there was some issue with the browser holding on to a stale regex or something. I restarted the browser and it started working as expected. Thanks for your input Héctor.